# Получить индекс выбранного элемента из кастомного ListView

Tags: android, listview

Возник вопрос, не могу достать индекс выбранного элемента. То есть у меня есть `RadioButton`, которая дает только одиночный выбор. Я бы хотел узнать индекс(номер) выбранного пункта

**Адаптер**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private RadioButton mSelectedRB;
private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
private final FragmentActivity context;

private final List<Model> list;




public MyAdapter(FragmentActivity context, List<Model> objects) {
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = objects;

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(view == null){

       // view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mResourceId, parent, false);
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr);
        holder.radioBtn = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }


    holder.radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null){
                mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
            }

            mSelectedPosition = position;
            mSelectedRB = (RadioButton)v;
        }
    });


    if(mSelectedPosition != position){
        holder.radioBtn.setChecked(false);
    }else{
        holder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
        if(mSelectedRB != null && holder.radioBtn != mSelectedRB){
            mSelectedRB = holder.radioBtn;
        }
    }

    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());

    if(list.get(position).getImage() != null)
        Picasso.with(context).load(list.get(position).getImage()).resize(150,100).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.imageView);


    return view;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    protected  TextView       name;
    protected RadioButton     radioBtn;
    protected ImageView       imageView;
    }
}
```

**Использую во фрагменте**

```
lvPerv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvPerv);
     adapter2 = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),
                getModel(texnika_sobrListOne));
        lvPerv.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

Пробовал получать так, но получаю ответ -1

```
 Log.e("TEST", String.valueOf(lvPerv.getCheckedItemPosition()));
```

Пробовал через события. Ну он вообще не реагирует

```
   lvPerv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Log.d("test", "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = "
                    + id);
        }
    });
```

Comment: а `getItemId()` такой и должен быть?

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33198617/5797206), может поможет

Answer (score 0):

Вы же сами управляете выбранной позицией в адаптере через переменную `mSelectedPosition`. Просто добавьте метод для её получения:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ...
    public int getSelectedPosition() {
        return mSelectedPosition;
    }
    ...
}
```

И вызывайте из фрагмента там, где она вам нужна:

```
Log.e("TEST", String.valueOf(adapter2.getSelectedPosition()));
```